# Which spells inflict the poisoned condition?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, conditions

Which current 5e spells are capable of inflicting the [poisoned](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/appendix-a-conditions#Poisoned) condition?

All I've been able to find so far is *Ray of Sickness*. Is this the only spell available that causes this condition?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## As of 1/17/2020, just *Ray of Sickness* and *Contagion*

Based on the current official spells as of 1/17/2020, the only spells that confer the **poisoned** condition are:

- *[Ray of Sickness](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/ray-of-sickness)* (PHB, 271)
- *[Contagion](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/contagion)* (PHB, 227)

I found these using [DNDbeyond's Spell search and filtering for condition:Poisoned](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells?filter-class=0&filter-search=&filter-condition=11&filter-verbal=&filter-somatic=&filter-material=&filter-concentration=&filter-ritual=&filter-sub-class=).

Comment: Perfect thanks! I didn't realize dndbeyond had a condition filter on their spell search.

Answer (score 20):

## Direct

There are two spell which directly cause the poisoned condition:

- [*Ray of Sickness*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/ray-of-sickness)
- [*Contagion*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/contagion)

## Indirect

There are however a number of spell which will let us summon creatures which then can cause the poisoned condition. In general, inflicting the condition will be contingent on the creature hitting, and the target failing a saving throw.

- [*Create Homunculus*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/create-homunculus) creates — as it name suggests — a [homunculus](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/homunculus) which, while not great in combat for the price you pay, can inflict the poisoned condition.
- [*Summon Greater Demon*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/summon-greater-demon) lets you summon for example a [rutterkin](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/rutterkin). If you upcast to 7th level you could instead summon a [shoosuva](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/shoosuva), which packs more of a punch and throws in paralyzed on the poisoned creature. [*Summon Lesser Demons*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/summon-lesser-demons) can, if you sweet talk your DM, summon [dretches](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/dretch) who emit poisonous gas. Summon demons at your own risk.
- [*Conjure Fey*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/conjure-fey) and [*Conjure Woodland Beings*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/conjure-woodland-beings) lets you summon [sprites](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/sprite) whose shortbows are tipped with poison.
- [*Conjure Fey*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/conjure-fey) and [*conjure animals*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/conjure-animals) can summon certain beasts which inflict the poisoned condition, but only do so when the target reaches 0 hit points, which is for most purposes too late. Eg. [giant wasp](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/giant-wasp), [giant spider](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/giant-spider), and [giant centipede](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/giant-centipede). The traditional venomous beasts (say [giant poisonous snake](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/giant-poisonous-snake)) deals poison damage, but do not inflict the condition.
- [*Conjure Celestial*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/conjure-celestial) can summon a [cuatl](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/couatl)
- [*Infernal Calling*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/infernal-calling) can summon a [bearded devil](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/bearded-devil)
- Additionally, you can use [*polymorph*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/polymorph), [*true polymorph*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/true-polymorph), [*shape change*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/shape-change), [*animal shapes*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/animal-shapes), or [*mass polymorph*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/mass-polymorph) to turn yourself and/or your companions into a creature form which can inflict the poisoned condition.

Answer (score 2):

### The only spells are *contagion* and *ray of sickness*

D&D Beyond allows you to [search through spells](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells) and one of the sorting options is "Conditions" and in particular "[Poisoned](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells?filter-condition=11)". This gives spells that mention the condition, which is why *lesser restoration*, *protection from poison*, and *feign death* appear. However it also lists [*contagion*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/contagion) and [*ray of sickness*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/ray-of-sickness):

> Your touch inflicts disease. Make a melee spell attack against a creature within your reach. **On a hit, the target is poisoned.** At the end of each of the poisoned target's turns, the target must make a Constitution saving throw. If the target succeeds on three of these saves, it is no longer poisoned, and the spell ends. If the target fails three of these saves, the target is no longer poisoned, but choose one of the diseases below. The target is subjected to the chosen disease for the spell's duration [...]

> A ray of sickening greenish energy lashes out toward a creature within range. Make a ranged spell attack against the target. On a hit, the target takes 2d8 poison damage and must make a Constitution saving throw. **On a failed save, it is also poisoned until the end of your next turn.**